# Python - Including external libraries in version control

Tags: python, svn

We are a small team trying to work on a python project using eclipse + pydev.
For our version control we use cloudforge SVN and the subclipse plugin.

I am trying to figure out what is the right way to include external libs which are normally installed
locally to the python in Lib/site-packages.

I tried several ways but some of them made some complications.
I am looking for the best-practice method for this matter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder why you would want to do this. I would do this only for very few selected libraries which you don't download as part of your build process. For anything else, you just specify the libraries you need (possibly pinning the versions you need) and / or setup a PyPi mirror if the amount of packages you need is big enough.

Comment: And if I do download the libraries. How can I include them in the project and not int Lib/site-packages ?

Comment: I assume you use one of the Python package tools, e.g. [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip) or [setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html). For any package ("egg") you're working, you can [declare dependencies](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#declaring-dependencies) which will then get downloaded as required. If you don't want these packages to end up in site-packages, take a look at [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [svn:externals](http://beerpla.net/2009/06/20/how-to-properly-set-svn-svnexternals-property-in-svn-command-line/). Example:

```
svn propset svn:externals 'akismet http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/akismet/trunk'
svn commit
```

Your next update is going to incorporate the external source from http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/akismet/trunk in the akismet directory. Hope that helps...